# Listening-in tty in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, tty

I try to find an easy way to listen to the exchange with the desired tty in Linux. A have hardware device whose interface is exposed as /dev/ttyAMA0  and some drivers on system interact with it. I want to dump all transfers (or at least in one direction) to uart/file etc. I don't want to change something in it, just duplicate. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: "*I try to find an easy way ...*" -- The easiest way would probably be to (electrically) tap each wire, and then connect each to the RxD of a UART.  So you would need two more UARTs.

Comment: There's an excellent tool called socat. Also, look here; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/how-can-i-monitor-serial-port-traffic

Comment: There is a tool called `ttysnoop`. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do what I want was just use strace. In strace log I found all necessary info.